What does KeyError: 'zmq-pub-channel-opened' mean?
Can anybody tell me if this is an issue when loading the zeromq plugin for Core Lightning?
2024-06-09T14:54:53.169Z INFO    plugin-cl-zmq.py: Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-06-09T14:54:53.169Z INFO    plugin-cl-zmq.py:   File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/pyln/client/plugin.py\">
2024-06-09T14:54:53.169Z INFO    plugin-cl-zmq.py:     result = self._exec_func(method.func, request)
2024-06-09T14:54:53.169Z INFO    plugin-cl-zmq.py:              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-06-09T14:54:53.169Z INFO    plugin-cl-zmq.py:   File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/pyln/client/plugin.py\">
2024-06-09T14:54:53.169Z INFO    plugin-cl-zmq.py:     ret = func(*ba.args, **ba.kwargs)
2024-06-09T14:54:53.169Z INFO    plugin-cl-zmq.py:           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-06-09T14:54:53.169Z INFO    plugin-cl-zmq.py:   File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/pyln/client/plugin.py\">
2024-06-09T14:54:53.169Z INFO    plugin-cl-zmq.py:     return self._exec_func(self.child_init, request)
2024-06-09T14:54:53.169Z INFO    plugin-cl-zmq.py:            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-06-09T14:54:53.169Z INFO    plugin-cl-zmq.py:   File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/pyln/client/plugin.py\">
2024-06-09T14:54:53.169Z INFO    plugin-cl-zmq.py:     ret = func(*ba.args, **ba.kwargs)
2024-06-09T14:54:53.169Z INFO    plugin-cl-zmq.py:           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-06-09T14:54:53.169Z INFO    plugin-cl-zmq.py:   File \"/home/main/.lightning/reckless/plugins/plugins/zmq/cl-zmq.py\",>
2024-06-09T14:54:53.169Z INFO    plugin-cl-zmq.py:     Setup.check_option_warnings(options, plugin)
2024-06-09T14:54:53.169Z INFO    plugin-cl-zmq.py:   File \"/home/main/.lightning/reckless/plugins/plugins/zmq/cl-zmq.py\",>
2024-06-09T14:54:53.169Z INFO    plugin-cl-zmq.py:     for endpoint in Setup._iter_endpoints_not_ok(options):
2024-06-09T14:54:53.169Z INFO    plugin-cl-zmq.py:   File \"/home/main/.lightning/reckless/plugins/plugins/zmq/cl-zmq.py\",>
2024-06-09T14:54:53.169Z INFO    plugin-cl-zmq.py:     endpoint = options[endpoint_opt]
2024-06-09T14:54:53.169Z INFO    plugin-cl-zmq.py:                ~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-06-09T14:54:53.169Z INFO    plugin-cl-zmq.py: KeyError: 'zmq-pub-channel-opened'
2024-06-09T14:54:53.169Z INFO    plugin-cl-zmq.py:

I'm running the example-subscriber.py file and I never see a shutdown event logged. I did add shutdown to the notification list.
python3 example-subscriber.py --zmq-sub-shutdown=tcp://127.0.0.1:5555

Here's how I'm starting the plugin:
lightningd --regtest --daemon --plugin=/home/main/.lightning/reckless/plugins/plugins/zmq/cl-zmq.py --log-file=/home/main/.lightning/logs.txt --zmq-pub-shutdown=tcp://127.0.0.1:5555


Hi, I updated the formatting in your post, and edited the title to give a sense of what the question is about. Please feel free to further edit the title, if you feel that I didn’t capture the intent of your post.

KeyError is a generic python error indicating that a key does not exist in a dict. In this case, there is a dict named options, and the code was trying to find a key named zmq-pub-channel-opened in options, but it does not exist, so Python threw a KeyError. This seems like a bug in the ZMQ plugin and I would suggest opening an issue in its github repo.

Will do. Thank you for the response.
